# Cannot find a safe socket path in '/tmp'

Tags: firefox, chmod, tmp

A while ago I accidentally ran `chmod 777 /`, and stopped it as soon as I realized what I had done. Unfortunately, it must have gotten to my `/tmp` directory, because whenever I start to run Firefox now, this is the error I get:

> ** ERROR **: Cannot find a safe socket path in '/tmp'
>   
> Trace/breakpoint trap

I can't find much information on the Internet about this problem, and I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox - but nothing helped.

How can I provide a "safe socket path in '/tmp'" for Firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/tmp` should have the sticky bit set, so

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

`chmod 777 /` wouldn't change permissions on `/tmp` though, unless the command actually had the `-R` switch too. If you did have `-R` on that `chmod`, and even if you were quick in aborting it, you've likely hosed your system to the point where fixing it will require much more work than a reinstall.

Anyway, using `chmod 777` on *any* file or directory is always wrong. Don't do it. Learn how permissions work and do it properly. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Permissions

Comment: I get:
chmod: changing permissions of '/tmp': Read-only file system